# GraphQL Ruby integrate with solidus searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, searchkick, solidus, graphql-ruby

i'm currently working on an ecommerce project, and start to implement graphql ruby with my solidus, now i'm about to build on faceted search using solidus searchkick

there is a custom function provided by solidus_searchkick

```
searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(fields: fields))
@products = searcher.retrieve_products
```

my idea was to pass the params to graphql query and perform the search while return the products list

```
query facetQuery($params: String){
  viewer {
    facetProduct(params: $params){ ... }
  }
}
```

However if i put

```
connection :facetProduct, Types::ProductType.connection_type do
    resolve -> (obj, args, context) {
      searcher = build_searcher(params)
      searcher.retrieve_products
    }
  end
```

i got a problem build_search is not defined, is there a way to integrate this function directly to graphql, currently i solved this problem over api, via httparty which is not very elegant solution